# Having trouble with Rspec expect(double).to receive(:message)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Having been inspired by Sandi Metz's approach to writing tests (http://www.confreaks.com/videos/2452-railsconf2013-the-magic-tricks-of-testing), I am trying to refactor a test for a Rails controller to assert that it is sending a command message properly.

Here are the relevant parts of the Application:

`class DealsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:reset]
      deal_filter.reset
 ...`

`class ApplicationController
  def deal_filter
   ...
   @deal_filter ||= DealFilter.new(args)
  end
...`

`class DealFilter
  def reset
    ...do work...
  end
...`

And here is the rspec test:

`describe DealsController do
   it "should send 'reset' to the deal_filter" do
     df = instance_double("DealFilter")
     get :index, reset: "true"
     expect(df).to receive(:reset)
   end
end`

The test results that keep coming back are:

`1) DealsController GET index for any user params contain 'reset' should send 'reset' to the deal_filter
     Failure/Error: expect(df).to receive(:reset)
       (Double "DealFilter (instance)").reset(any args)
           expected: 1 time with any arguments
           received: 0 times with any arguments`

I have already confirmed that the reset param is being sent through the test and that the controller is following the appropriate path, yet the test continues to fail.

Can anyone suggest a possible reason for the failure or resources for further study? I am relatively new to object oriented thinking and using mocks with Rspec. Could it be that I have misunderstood the role of doubles?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're expecting your instance_double to be used automatically somewhere within the index action. That's not how doubles work. You can create a double and use it for things, but your code in the controller doesn't (and shouldn't) know anything about that double and so won't ever call anything on it.

For an example of how an instance double can actually be used see [this documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double).

Another issue with your expectation is that you're not setting it early enough. When you expect an object to receive a method call there needs to be something that happens after that which would invoke that method. In your example the expectation to receive :reset is the very last line of your example.

I'd recommend [reading up](https://www.google.com/search?q=controller%20spec%20examples) on how other people have tested controllers with rspec as a good starting place.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your double gets used. I think the best way to do that here is to stub the `deal_filter` method to return the double.

I addition I would isolate the expection, so that it's the only thing in the `it` block. This will make it easier to add more expections without duplication the setup logic.

```
describe DealsController do
  let(:df) { instance_double("DealFilter") }

  before do
    allow(controller).to receive(:deal_filter).and_return(df)
    get :index, reset: "true"
  end

  it "should send 'reset' to the deal_filter" do
    expect(df).to have_received(:reset)
  end
end
```

Comment: Your code example was very helpful. The stubbing syntax allow() led me down the right path. However, @Coenwulf was right about the order of the expectation. I had to place `get :index` AFTER setting the expectation.

Comment: I should have used `have_received` in my example. It's updated now.